# Laravel: A lot of errors

Tags: laravel, delay, lag

```
[Mon Jul  9 20:21:19 2018] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in D:\Projects\shop\back-end\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 85
[Mon Jul  9 20:21:19 2018] PHP Stack trace:
[Mon Jul  9 20:21:19 2018] PHP   1. {main}() D:\Projects\shop\back-end\server.php:0
[Mon Jul  9 20:21:19 2018] PHP   2. require_once() D:\Projects\shop\back-end\server.php:21
[Mon Jul  9 20:21:19 2018] PHP   3. App\Http\Kernel->handle() D:\Projects\shop\back-end\public\index.php:55
[Mon Jul  9 20:21:19 2018] PHP   4. App\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter() D:\Projects\shop\back-end\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:116
```

full: https://pastebin.com/aMhFKunB

Somebody know what is this.. ? My Laravel application is working very hard, delay between requests and responses on localhost.

Comment: Can you add the content of `Grammar.php on line 85`

Comment: if (! is_null($command->onUpdate)) {
            $sql .= " on update {$command->onUpdate}";
        }

Comment: @Hackerman where is $sql .= is line 85.

Comment: You are concatenating, creating dynamic `sql`? Is the answer is `yes`, can you add a `print_r($sql);` at the end of the concatenations...I think that you are getting an expensive query that exceds the maximum execution time of 60 seconds...you have two paths, you either optimize that mega sql, or you can increase the `max execution time` in order to give the server more time to process the query...the choice is yours.

Comment: `Grammar.php` is what laravel uses to convert Query builder queries to native queries on your database. What query is being performed ? Check [query events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#listening-for-query-events) to figure out what is actually running.

Comment: Try to upgrade to the latest 5.6.x please. Also, PHP 5.5.9 has known bugs. Try with the latest 7.0.x or php7.1

Comment: @AliMohammed    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "laravel/passport": "6.0.*",
        "laravel/socialite": "^3.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
    },

Comment: @Hackerman I used XDebug right now, I get a lot of throw OAuthServerException::accessDenied('Access token has been revoked'); in a infinite loop. After is throw that error I get at this function "public function isExpression($value)" the "Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!" error.

Comment: @Hackerman Now I deleted the token. Weird thing to say. If I reinstall the passport, how I can do to prevent these errors?